# Is it necessary to convert a python script from bpy.context / bpy.ops to bpy.data to run it withou gui via command-line?

Tags: python, command-line

I would like to run the following script via command-line and no gui:

```
import bpy
import os

# switch on nodes
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.node_tree.nodes.active = scene.node_tree.nodes['Composite']
scene.render.use_compositing = True
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

# assign a color
bg_col = [1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]

# change value
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes["color-background"].outputs[0].default_value = bg_col
print("new background color set to "+ str(bg_col))

# ----- LOAD IMAGE -----
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
#print(directory)

# Load a new image
mat = bpy.data.materials['LogoMaterial']
nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

logo_texture = nodes["logo-texture"]
#load new logo texture
logo_texture.image = bpy.data.images.load(directory+"/tex//logo-2k.png", check_existing=True)
print("new logo texture added")

#create a sequence editor
if not scene.sequence_editor:
    scene.sequence_editor_create()

#clear the VSE, then add an audio file
scene.sequence_editor_clear()
my_context = bpy.context.area.type
#print(str(my_context))
my_context = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
#print(str(my_context))
bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add(filepath="//audio/0A1.wav", files=[{"name":"0A1.wav", "name":"0A1.wav"}], relative_path=True, frame_start=1, channel=1)
print("loaded new sound")
my_context = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

If it is necessary, how would I go about converting it to only using `bpy.data` instead of `bpy.context` and `bpy.ops`?

Below is a part where I try to replace an audio file in the Video Sequence Editor just using `bpy.data`, however it only removes the audio datablock, loads a new audio, but does not associate the audio to the audiostrip in the VSE timeline.

```
if "0A1.wav" in bpy.data.sounds:
    sound = bpy.data.sounds["0A1.wav"]
    print("removing sound ", sound)
    bpy.data.sounds.remove(sound)
    print("loading new sound ", sound)
    bpy.data.sounds.load("/audio//0B.wav")
```

Comment: So what result *does* it produce?

Comment: I have a feeling that what you want to do is use `scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name, filpath, channel, frame_start)` to add a soundstrip, and to change sound for that strip  set `scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all['goober.wav'].sound` to your newly loaded sound. As it is you are just loading a new sound and not assoc it with a strip.

Comment: adding a soundfile with `scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name, filpath, channel, frame_start)` works, but the fundamental question remains if this still works when rendering without gui on the command-line.
The second code in my question was an attempt to do the same thing with bpy.data - I did not find anything how to associate the strip with the loaded audio...

Comment: @RayMairlot The `bpy.data.sounds.remove(sound)` of the second code part works, the audio strip gets red stripes - what I don't know is how to associate the loaded audio to the strip without using bpy.context...

Comment: .... `scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all['some_name'].sound` is the sound of the soundstrip "some_name", just need to know its name, or give it a custom prop or look for the one with the sound you want to replace .. eg. `[s for s in sequences_all if getattr(s, "sound", None) == sound]`  Even easier if you still have ref from `soundstrip = sequences.new_sound(..,)` then you can  simply `soundstirp.sound = sound`.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you, but that still requires `bpy.context`, which means I cant run it via command-line, which is my main issue. How would I do the same thing with just `bpy.data`?

Comment: why on earth does this require context? just need a scene ie `scene = bpy.data.scenes.get("some_scene")`. `scene.seque......`

Comment: @batFINGER I will try this out, sorry for being so slow to comprehend. It is all a little confusing to me still.

Comment: @batFINGER this works from within the gui, but not via commandline:
`scene = bpy.data.scenes.get("SceneA")
seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
seq.new_sound(name='0D.wav', 
        filepath="//audio\\0D.wav",
        channel=1, frame_start=1)`

**error from cmd**
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\_PROJECTS\NU-LOGO-ID\Blends\audiotest.py", line 10, in <module>
    seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sequence_editor'`

Comment: Try create one with `sequence_editor = scene.sequence_editor or scene.sequence_editor_create()` ?

Comment: @batFINGER no dice, but thank you for your help! running blender headless seems to be a whole different animal...

Comment: I made a little test file in Text editor named Text (default) using all code listed (by me) above and it worked fine. `blender -b sometestfile.blend --python-text  Text`  Post your script. Chances are YOU are doing something "fundamentally" incorrectly.  Your last message implies there is no scene named "SceneA" in your file.

Comment: @batFINGER I finally fixed it with your help! My brain was fried after a long day. Thank you so much!
`import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.data.scenes.get("Scene")
if not scene.sequence_editor:
    scene.sequence_editor_create()


scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name='0D.wav', filepath="//audio\\0D.wav", channel=1, frame_start=1)`

Comment: good one, write up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`bpy.context` works perfectly fine from the command line. [Here](https://github.com/ldo/render-useful) is a set of scripts for doing useful things with Blender from the command line, and a couple of them (`render-batch` and `apply-compositor`) make references to `bpy.context`.

Note also the technique of wrapping the Python code in a shell script, so the user can conveniently invoke the scripts as though they were commands in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @batFINGER I finally fixed it!

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.data.scenes.get("Scene")
if not scene.sequence_editor:
    scene.sequence_editor_create()

scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_sound(name='0D.wav', filepath="//audio\\0D.wav", channel=1, frame_start=1)
```